# fast subsetting in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got a dataframe dat of size 30000 x 50. I also have a separate list that contains points to groupings of rows from this dataframe, e.g.,

```
rows <- list(c("34", "36", "39"), c("45", "46"))
```

This says that dataframe rows with rownames (not numeric row indeces, but character rownames(dat)) "34", "36", "39" constitute one grouping, and "45", "46" constitute another grouping.

Now I want to pull out the groupings from the dataframe into a parallel list, but my code (below) is really, really slow. How can I speed it up?

```
> system.time(lapply(rows, function(r) {dat[r, ]}))
   user  system elapsed 
 246.09    0.01  247.23
```

That's on a very fast computer, R 2.14.1 x64.

Comment: Could you give roughly how many elements in `rows` and roughly how many elements in `rows[[i]]`? Also, your rownames are all unique, right? (I've made a random `dat`, 30000x50, but I seem to be getting fast times for the `rows` I make up - they're probably not big enough?)

Comment: `rows` has about 15000 elements; `length(rows[[i]])` ranges from 1 to 50

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One of the main issues is the matching of row names -- the default in `[.data.frame` is partial matching of row names and you probably don't want that, so you're better off with `match`. To speed it up even further you can use `fmatch` from `fastmatch` if you want. This is a minor modification with some speedup:

```
# naive
> system.time(res1 <- lapply(rows,function(r) dat[r,]))
   user  system elapsed 
 69.207   5.545  74.787 

# match
> rn <- rownames(dat)
> system.time(res1 <- lapply(rows,function(r) dat[match(r,rn),]))
   user  system elapsed 
 36.810  10.003  47.082 

# fastmatch
> rn <- rownames(dat)
> system.time(res1 <- lapply(rows,function(r) dat[fmatch(r,rn),]))
   user  system elapsed 
 19.145   3.012  22.226
```

You can get further speed up by not using `[` (it is slow for data frames) but splitting the data frame (using `split`) if your `rows` are non-overlapping and cover all rows (and thus you can map each row to one entry in rows).

Depending on your actual data you may be better off with matrices that have by far faster subsetting operators since they are native.

Comment: fmatch is really quite magical. I now see these timings (compare to those in the question):
`user  system elapsed
   11.48    0.02   11.64`

Comment: ...but fmatch doesn't handle updates to the `table` arg: `s<-'a';fmatch('a',s);s[1]<-'b';fmatch('a',s)` The second time, fmatch should not find a match, but it does... In general, it seems dangerous to change NAMED objects, and also to rely on that they are never modified again...

Comment: Yes, and the docs warn about that. That's the price you pay for speed ;) Unfortunately there is no way in R to get notified on update. And the issue is not `NAMED` at all but the fact that R will happily copy the attribute onto a new object.

Comment: Actually, I found a way to identify the case that you illustrated (by storing the parent object in the hash), so the next release of `fastmatch` should be able to detect copied attributes that are out of sync. Thanks for the example :).

Comment: Great that you could address that case. And the NAMED issue is that you are "breaking the rules" by modifying a NAMED object by assigning a new attribute to it. Perhaps the benefits outweigh the risks in your case. A rule-abiding solution would be a bit more cumbersome to use: `m <- fmakeMap(table); fmatch(x, m)`

Answer (score 5):

### Update

My original post started with this erroneous statement:

> The problem with indexing via `rownames` and `colnames` is that you
>   are running a vector/linear scan for each element, eg. you are hunting
>   through each row to see which is named "36", then starting from the
>   beginning to do it again for "34".

Simon pointed out in the comments here that R apparently uses a hash table for indexing. Sorry for the mistake.

### Original Answer

*Note that the suggestions in this answer assume that you have non-overlapping subsets of data.*

If you want to keep your list-lookup strategy, I'd suggest storing the actual row indices in stead of string names.

An alternative is to store your "group" information as another column to your `data.frame`, then `split` your `data.frame` on its group, eg. let's say your recoded `data.frame` looks like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=sample(100, 10),
                  b=rnorm(10),
                  group=sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 10, replace=TRUE))
```

You could then do:

```
split(dat, dat$group)
$a
   a           b group
2 66 -0.08721261     a
9 62 -1.34114792     a

$b
    a          b group
1  32  0.9719442     b
5  79 -1.0204179     b
6  83 -1.7645829     b
7  73  0.4261097     b
10 44 -0.1160913     b

$c
   a          b group
3 77  0.2313654     c
4 74 -0.8637770     c
8 29  1.0046095     c
```

Or, depending on what you really want to do with your "splits", you can convert your `data.frame` to a [`data.table`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html) and set its key to your new `group` column:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(dat, key="group")
```

Now do your list thing -- which will give you the same result as the `split` above

```
 x <- lapply(unique(dat$group), function(g) dat[J(g),])
```

But you probably want to "work over your spits", and you can do that inline, eg:

```
ans <- dat[, {
  ## do some code over the data in each split
  ## and return a list of results, eg:
  list(nrow=length(a), mean.a=mean(a), mean.b=mean(b))
}, by="group"]

ans
     group nrow mean.a     mean.b
[1,]     a    2   64.0 -0.7141803
[2,]     b    5   62.2 -0.3006076
[3,]     c    3   60.0  0.1240660
```

You can do the last step in "a similar fashion" with [`plyr`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html), eg:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(dat, "group", summarize, nrow=length(a), mean.a=mean(a),
      mean.b=mean(b))
  group nrow mean.a     mean.b
1     a    2   64.0 -0.7141803
2     b    5   62.2 -0.3006076
3     c    3   60.0  0.1240660
```

But since you mention your dataset is quite large, I think you'd like the speed boost `data.table` will provide.

Comment: "The problem with indexing via rownames and colnames is that you are running a vector/linear scan for each element" - is plain wrong, R is not that stupid - it uses hash tables for indexing. However, since partial matching is the default you may do better by using `match` to avoid that (or preferably `fastmatch` since you'd like to re-use the hash table) - for examples I've added a response.

Comment: @SteveLianoglou, despite the error on the linear scan comment, thank you for demonstrating the use of `split`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one attempt at a speedup - it hinges on the fact that it is faster to look up a row index than to look up a row name, and so tries to make a mapping of rowname to rownumber in `dat`.

First create some data of the same size as yours and assign some numeric rownames:

```
> dat <- data.frame(matrix(runif(30000*50),ncol=50))
> rownames(dat) <- as.character(sample.int(nrow(dat)))
> rownames(dat)[1:5]
[1] "21889" "3050"  "22570" "28140" "9576"
```

Now generate a random `rows` with 15000 elements, each of 50 random numbers from 1 to 30000 (being row*names* in this case):

```
# 15000 groups of up to 50 rows each
> rows <- sapply(1:15000, function(i) as.character(sample.int(30000,size=sample.int(50,size=1))))
```

For timing purposes, try the method in your question (**ouch!**):

```
# method 1
> system.time((res1 <- lapply(rows,function(r) dat[r,])))
   user  system elapsed 
182.306   0.877 188.362
```

Now, try to make a mapping from row name to row number. `map[i]` should give the row number with name `i`.

**FIRST** if your row *names* are a permutation of `1:nrow(dat)` you're in luck! All you have to do is sort the rownames, and return the indices:

```
> map <- sort(as.numeric(rownames(dat)), index.return=T)$ix
# NOTE: map[ as.numeric(rowname) ] -> rownumber into dat for that rowname.
```

Now look up row indices instead of row names:

```
> system.time((res2 <- lapply(rows,function(r) dat[map[as.numeric(r)],])))
   user  system elapsed
 32.424   0.060  33.050
```

Check we didn't screw anything up (note it is sufficient to match the rownames since rownames are unique in R):

```
> all(rownames(res1)==rownames(res2))
[1] TRUE
```

So, a ~6x speedup. Still not amazing though...

**SECOND** If you're unlucky and your rownames are not at all related to `nrow(dat)`, you *could* try this, **but** only if `max(as.numeric(rownames(dat)))` is not too much bigger than `nrow(dat)`. It basically makes `map` with `map[rowname]` giving the row number, but since the rownames are not necessarily continuous any more there can be heaps of gaps in `map` which wastes a bit of memory:

```
map <- rep(-1,max(as.numeric(rownames(dat))))
obj <- sort(as.numeric(rownames(dat)), index.return=T)
map[obj$x] <- obj$ix
```

Then use `map` as before (`dat[map[as.numeric(r),]]`).

Answer (score 2):

You could try this modification:

```
system.time(lapply(rows, function(r) {dat[ rownames(dat) %in% r, ]}))
```

Comment: this one absolutely killed my computer -- I reckon `dat[rownames(dat) %in% r,]` is slower than `dat[r,]`

Comment: Yeah. This one almost doubles the time required. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with mathematical coffee that I too get fast times for this.

Don't know if it's possible but by unlisting as a vector and then converting to numeric you can get a speed boost.

```
dat <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30000*50), 30000, 50 ))
rows <- as.numeric(unlist(list(c("34", "36", "39"), c("45", "46"))))
system.time(lapply(rows, function(r) {dat[r, ]}))
```

EDIT:

```
dat$observ <- rownames(dat)
rownames(dat) <- 1:nrow(dat)
```

Comment: However the rows are row names not row indices, so `as.numeric` will cause the wrong rows to be extracted.

Comment: could the row names be converted to numeric or they actual character vectors?  If they're character vectors I'd suggest making that another variable/column and having numeric row names.  This gives you numeric rownames and retains your information. I'll demonstrate.

Comment: Yeah I get the character rownames problem now. It's possible a hash table could be used here but I'd see how DWin and mathematical coffee's solutions pan out first.